# UIImage initWithContentsOfFile:... - need to get only dimensions

Tags: file, uiimage, dimensions

I need to get only width and height from PNG file. Is it possible to do with `UIImage`? The reason is because sometimes (in rare cases with some images with odd width and RGB8 format) UIImage returns different dimension than `libpng`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found an answer here: http://oleb.net/blog/2011/09/accessing-image-properties-without-loading-the-image-into-memory/

```
#import <ImageIO/ImageIO.h>

NSURL *imageFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:...];
CGImageSourceRef imageSource = CGImageSourceCreateWithURL((CFURLRef)imageFileURL, NULL);
if (imageSource == NULL) {
    // Error loading image
    ...
    return;
}

NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                         [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO], (NSString *)kCGImageSourceShouldCache, 
                         nil];
CFDictionaryRef imageProperties = CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(imageSource, 0, (CFDictionaryRef)options);
if (imageProperties) {
    NSNumber *width = (NSNumber *)CFDictionaryGetValue(imageProperties, kCGImagePropertyPixelWidth);
    NSNumber *height = (NSNumber *)CFDictionaryGetValue(imageProperties, kCGImagePropertyPixelHeight);
    NSLog(@"Image dimensions: %@ x %@ px", width, height);
    CFRelease(imageProperties);
}
```

We can access any metadata from file without loading an image.